# Как оправить объект типа Image.Image в ВК

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, vkontakte-api, pil

Решил добавить возможность сделать скриншот. Но тут возникла проблема с загрузкой картинки в ВК.

Сделать скриншот и вернуть в виде байтов:

```py
def screen_shot():
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()

    image.save(imgByteArr, format='PNG')

    imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()

    return imgByteArr
```

Отправить скриншот:

```py
def send_photo(photo, id):
    a = vk.photos.getMessagesUploadServer()
    b = requests.post(a['upload_url'], files={'photo': photo}).json()

    c = vk.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(
        server=b['server'],
        photo=b['photo'], 
        hash=b['hash']
    )[0]

    d = f'photo{c["owner_id"]}_{c["id"]}'

    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=id,
        random_id=get_random_id(),
        message=f'Скрин ID: {id} | Время: {datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M %d.%m ")}',
        attachment=d
    )

send_photo(screen_shot(), id)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/333zl/Documents/Python/untitled/8.py", line 44, in <module>
        send_photo(screen_shot(), event.message['from_id'])
    File "C:/Users/333zl/Documents/Python/untitled/8.py", line 30, in send_photo
        c = vk.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(server=b['server'], photo=b['photo'], hash=b['hash'])[0]
    File "C:\Users\333zl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 681, in __call__
        return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\333zl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 646, in method
        raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photos_list is invalid
```

Однако если в функции `screen_shot` будет запись в файл и открытие потока:

```py
def screen_shot():
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    im.save('C:/Windows/Temp/im.jpeg', 'JPEG')    
    return open('C:/Windows/Temp/im.jpeg', 'rb')
```

тогда всё работает, но это лишние действия.

Что надо сделать с `ImageGrab`, чтобы отправить картинку в ВК без сохранения во временный файл?

Comment: Ошибка возникает из-за отсутствия имени у скриншота. Он подписан, но в памяти вашего компьютера не имеет именованного ID.  Этот вывод следует из расшифровки предоставленного лога.

Comment: P.S. Отмечают предпочтительность использования метода io.StringIO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем нашёл решение, надо добавить в `'photo:'`:

```
def screen_shots():
while True:
    a = vk.photos.getMessagesUploadServer()
    b = requests.post(a['upload_url'], files={'photo': ('screenshot.png', screen_shot(), 'image/png')}).json()
    photo = vk.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(server=b['server'], photo=b['photo'], hash=b['hash'])[0]
    d = f'photo{photo["owner_id"]}_{photo["id"]}'
    if len(photos) > 9:
        photos.pop(0)
    photos.append(d)
    time.sleep(5)
```